# PHP 7 SSH2.SFTP stat() bug work around

Tags: php-7, ssh2-sftp

I have an app the uses an SFTP connection to download files. It was working correctly in PHP 5.6, not so much in PHP 7. The error I get is as follows:

PHP Warning:  filesize(): stat failed for ssh2.sftp ...

My code is as follows:

```
 public function retrieveFiles($downloadTargetFolder,$remoteFolder = '.') {

            $fileCount = 0;

                echo "\nSftpFetcher retrieveFiles\n";

        $con = ssh2_connect($this->host,$this->port) or die("Couldn't connect\n");
        if($this->pubKeyFile){
                $isAuth = ssh2_auth_pubkey_file($con, $this->user, $this->pubKeyFile, $this->privKeyFile);
        } else {
                $isAuth = ssh2_auth_password($con,  $this->user,  $this->pass);
        };


        if ($isAuth) {

                $sftp = ssh2_sftp($con);
                $rd = "ssh2.sftp://{$sftp}{$remoteFolder}";

                if (!$dir = opendir($rd)) {
                        echo "\nCould not open the remote directory\n";
                } else {
                        $files = array();
                                while (false != ($file = readdir($dir))) {
                                    if ($file == "." || $file == "..")
                                        continue;
                                    $files[] = $file;
                                }

                        if (is_array($files)) {
                            foreach ($files as $remoteFile) {
                                                echo "\ncheck file: $remoteFile vs filter: " . $this->filter."\n";
                                if ($this->filter !== null && strpos($remoteFile,$this->filter) === false) {
                                    continue;
                                }
                                                echo "file matched\n";
                                $localFile = $downloadTargetFolder . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . basename($remoteFile);


                                //$result = ftp_get($con,$localFile,$remoteFile,FTP_BINARY);
                                $result = true;
                                // Remote stream
                                if (!$remoteStream = @fopen($rd."/".$remoteFile, 'r')) {
                                        echo "Unable to open the remote file $remoteFolder/$remoteFile\n";
                                        $return = false;
                                } else {
                                        // Local stream
                                        if (!$localStream = @fopen($localFile, 'w')) {
                                                echo "Unable to open the local file $localFile\n";
                                                $return = false;
                                        } else {
                                                // Write from our remote stream to our local stream

                                                $read = 0;
                                                $fileSize = filesize($rd."/".$remoteFile);
                                                while ($read < $fileSize && ($buffer = fread($remoteStream, $fileSize - $read))) {
                                                        $read += strlen($buffer);
                                                        if (fwrite($localStream, $buffer) === FALSE) {
                                                                echo "Unable to write the local file $localFile\n";
                                                                $return = false;
                                                                break;
                                                        }
                                                }


                                                echo "File retrieved";
                                                // Close
                                                fclose($localStream);
                                                fclose($remoteStream);

                                        }

                                }

                                if ($result) {
                                    $fileCount++;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        ssh2_exec($con, 'exit');
                        unset($con);
                }

        } else {
                echo "Error authenticating the user ".$this->user."\n";
        }

            return $fileCount;

    }
}
```

After some research I found there was an issue with stat():

http://dougal.gunters.org/blog/2016/01/18/wordpress-php7-and-updates-via-php-ssh2/
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71376

**My question**

Is there a workaround to allow me to download via SFTP given my current **code** or is there another library someone can recommend to use instead?

My PHP version: 
PHP 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 (cli) ( NTS )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quoting [PHP ssh2.sftp opendir/readdir fix](http://paul-m-jones.com/archives/6439),

> Instead of using `"ssh2.sftp://$sftp"` as a stream path, convert $sftp to an integer like so: `"ssh2.sftp://" . intval($sftp) . "/"`. Then it will work just fine.

The reason for the change is as follows:

> PHP 5.6.28 (and apparently 7.0.13) introduced a security fix to URL parsing, that caused the string interpolation of the $sftp resource handle to no-longer be recognized as a valid URL. In turn, that causes opendir(), readdir(), etc. to fail when you use an $sftp resource in the path string, after an upgrade to one of those PHP versions.

As for other libraries...  only other library I'm aware of is [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/), which has an emulator of sorts for libssh2:

https://github.com/phpseclib/libssh2-compatibility-layer

That "emulator" could certainly be improved upon tho. Like a composer.json file ought to be added, etc.

Comment: Just ran into this and your answer saved the day. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you :) bizarrely had this issue after an os update, Php 5.6, intval did the trick. Now I only spent one hour on the problem as opposed to many more

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with php 8.0.

Try putting the filesize command before the fopens.