# PHP attempting to download file via SFTP but receive stat failed error when calculating filesize

Tags: php, sftp, ssh2-sftp

Trying to download files from a SFTP location.

I'm using `intval` on the stream as this is designed to fix a bug I've read about here: [PHP 7 SSH2.SFTP stat() bug work around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40921520/php-7-ssh2-sftp-stat-bug-work-around). I'm running PHP 7.0.33.

However, it still fails on the `filesize` command

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('remote.host', 22);

ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'user', 'pass');

$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);

$remoteDir = '/Data/';


$handle = opendir("ssh2.sftp://".intval($sftp)."$remoteDir"); //works with intval, fails without  

while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))){

        $local = fopen('localdata/'.$entry, 'w');

        $remote = fopen("ssh2.sftp://".intval($sftp)."$remoteDir$entry", 'r'); //works with intval, fails without

        $fileSize = filesize("ssh2.sftp://".intval($sftp)."$remoteDir$entry"); //fails with or without intval

        $buffer = fread($remote, $filesize - $read);

        fwrite($local, '$buffer');

}
```

The error is:

```
PHP Warning:  filesize(): stat failed for ssh2.sftp://5/ Data/remote_file.csv in /var/www/html/sftp_test.php on line 58
Segmentation fault
```

I don't understand why `opendir` and `fopen` work but `filesize` fails. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thank you

UPDATE:

I gave up trying to get this to work. I'm using this instead. Less sophisticated but it does the job

```
copy("ssh2.sftp://".intval($sftp)."/{$remoteDir}{$file}", "localdata/$file");
```

Comment: PHP should never segfault. I would check for similar bugs on their bug tracker and submit a new one if you don't find an existing one.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with php 8.0. 

Try putting the filesize command before the fopen.